# How do I determine the number of rows and columns in a Swift [[AnyObject]]

Tags: swift

Does anyone know how to determine the dimensions of a multidimensional array in Swift?  For example, the function below needs to accept a `[[AnyObject]]` of unknown size.  I then need to iterate through the rows of one column.

```
public convenience init(variableNames:[String], observations: [[AnyObject]]){
    self.init()

    for i in 0..<numRows {
        //do something with one column of observations
    }
}
```

The total number of elements is provided by

```
observations.count
```

which is not useful in this case.  Ideally I would be able to do:

```
(rows, cols) = observations.size
```

or something similar, but I haven't been able to find any such method.  Going the long way I can determine the number of columns by

```
let cols = observations[i].count
```

but because

```
let columnOfArray = observations[][i]
```

does not seem to be allowed I am stuck trying to determine the number of rows.  Does anyone have an answer?

Comment: I dont know that you are trying to achive. Arent you getting the number of columns with observations[i].count ? Please provide more information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about this?

```
    var a : [[AnyObject]] = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
    var row = a.count
    var col = a[0].count
    println("row = \(row)") // "row = 2"
    println("col = \(col)") // "col = 3"
```

But be carreful because this `var a : [[AnyObject]] = [[1,2,3],[4,6]]`
will return the same since the [[AnyObject]] is not a rectangular, each array in it can have different size.

If you know that all lines have same number of row, you are safe, else, there is no solution, you will have to count cols of each rows.

```
    for(var i=0;i<row;++i)
    {
        println("col = \(a[i].count)")
    }
```

**This returns:**

```
"col = 3"
"col = 2"
```

Comment: Gah!  I misunderstood [[AnyObject]].count.  Also [[AnyObject]] is an array of arrays, not a single array.  Thank you!